How to resolve ':app ' execution failure due to 'androidx.core:core:1.15.0-alpha01' dependency?
I'm encountering an issue when building my Android project. The build fails with the following error:
`Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

   1.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.15.0-alpha01' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 35 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-34.

       Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
       plugin 8.1.1 is 34.

       Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
       plugin to one that supports 35, then update this project to use
       compileSdk of at least 35.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

`
Additional Info:
SDK Tools
SDK Platforms
I tried updating the compileSdkVersion to 35 in my build.gradle file, but encountered the following error:
`Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not determine the dependencies of null.
Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-35
`

Additionally, I attempted to force the dependency to an earlier version by adding implementation('androidx.core:core:1.13.1') to my app/build.gradle file, but the error remained the same.

I have same issue.

Upgrade the compileSDK to 35 is the best solution

add this code to app/build.gradle
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "androidx.core:core:1.13.1"
    }
}


this is the correct solution

I don't want to go down a rabbit hole of research to figure out what you are saying here, but i suspect this is the solution I am looking for.  Can you please tell me where this code needs to be placed?  I see in Android Studio what looks like a folder called 'Gradle Scripts' and under it i see two things that both look like files called build.gradle.kts (one says Project and the other Module after).  does this code go in there somewhere?

Fixed it...  Go to Files -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Compile Sdk Version -> change it to 35 (or whatever version your thing is complaining about)
That should solve the problem.

same here worked for me ass well

Very slight difference if using .kts, force("...").

downgrading is not best solution. upgrade the compileSDK to 35.

I found two solutions to this problem.
Solution 1
Downgrade dependency version.

Open app/build.gradle file or (Gradle Scripts/build.gradle.kts if you are using the Android folder structure).
Locate the dependencies block.
Modify the dependency version for androidx.core:core-ktx

Before:
dependencies {

implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.15.0")
...

After:
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
...

NB: If you are on the latest version of Android Studio like Ladybug
change the line
implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)

to
implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx.v1131)

Solution 2
Change compileSdk to 35.

Open app/build.gradle file or (Gradle Scripts/build.gradle.kts if you are using the Android folder structure).
Locate the android block.
Modify the compileSdk to  35

Before:
android {
    namespace = "com.example.lemonade"
    compileSdk = 34
    ...

After:
android {
    namespace = "com.example.lemonade"
    compileSdk = 35
    ...


For the first option from @gtxtreme answer:

Select targetSDK  < 35, e.g. 34:

android {
    namespace = "com.example.prjname"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.prjname"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34


Select another version of core library which is stable, e.g. 1.13.1, add it to build.gradle.kts as pointed here:

dependencies {
    val core_version = "1.13.1"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation("androidx.core:core:$core_version")
    // Kotlin
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_version")


This resolved my issue.

Pretty self explanatory
androidx.core:core:1.15.0-alpha01 requires you to use a targetSDK of 35 i.e. Android 15 which is a Developer Preview Version, and might be unstable
What you can do is select a version of the library here, if you'd not want to update
In general always be on the latest stable, unless you actually require something explicitly
Another option would be to change your targetSDK to 35, which I will not recommend, since Android 15 is not stable as of writing this answer

I changed to targetSDK to 35 & have question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78627947/failed-to-find-platform-sdk-with-path-platformsandroid-35. Can you help with it? It seems that I should revert back to targetSDK version <35 which is stable.

Do you know how change androidx.core:core:1.15.0-alpha01 to lower version so, it can be used with targetSDK version <35. I think that is the rootcause.

I have given you a link above you can select the latest stable 1.13

Changing to target SDK 35 caused another issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/78627947/6629458

Cool, please mark whichever answer worked for you as accepted

Thanks bro, I saw some guidance in this thread which I believe can solve the issue targetSDK 35 but I've not tried yet because it's OK for me with targetSDK 34 now.

android {
namespace = "com.example.prjname"
compileSdkPreview "VanillaIceCream"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.example.prjname"
    minSdk = 26
    targetSdk = 34

using like this could be able to run the app and build apk/aab file,
but when i install apk file. it shows an error named "App not installed as package appears to be invalid"

I have the same problem.
I tried the solution describe in the thread
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.13.1'
...

But the result it the same:
An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

  1.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.15.0-alpha01' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 35 or later of the
      Android APIs.
...

The only solution to build my application is to use the pre version of the SDK API 35 with the parameters in build.gradle file:
   compileSdkPreview "VanillaIceCream"
    
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdk 34
...

But in this case I can push my application on the google play console because it return the error : "You cannot upload a test-only APK or Android App Bundle."

I resolve my problem :-). I have just update the version of a external library in the  build.gradle file.

I managed to solve my problem, which was caused by a third-party library, specifically react-native-screen-brightness in my case. After removing it from the project, the application started working again.
To identify this issue, I created another react-native project and installed libraries one by one until I found the one causing the errors.

it's not the react-native-screen-brightness library which is causing the problem but the version you may consider using 1 old version with Android SDK 34.

androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01 will solve your problem

Hey I have exactly the same issue but with Managed Workflow.
Does someone have an idea how to fix it ?
Here's my package.json
I've tried to delete react-native-screen-brightness but it did not fix the issue.

{
"name": "lotyproject",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start --dev-client",
"android": "expo run:android",
"ios": "expo run:ios",
"web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
"@adrianso/react-native-device-brightness": "^1.2.7",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.24.5",
"@expo/config-plugins": "~8.0.0",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
"@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.1.0",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.5",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.4",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
"axios": "^1.6.2",
"axios-auth-refresh": "^3.3.6",
"date-fns": "^2.30.0",
"expo": "^51.0.14",
"expo-barcode-scanner": "~13.0.1",
"expo-camera": "~15.0.6",
"expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
"expo-device": "~6.0.2",
"expo-font": "~12.0.5",
"expo-location": "~17.0.1",
"expo-notifications": "~0.28.1",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
"expo-updates": "~0.25.11",
"npm-upgrade": "^2.0.4",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.2",
"react-native-animated-placeholder-textinput": "^0.0.9",
"react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^4.0.0",
"react-native-drop-shadow": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
"react-native-keychain": "^8.1.2",
"react-native-maps": "1.14.0",
"react-native-pager-view": "6.3.0",
"react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
"react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
"react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
"react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.3.1",
"react-native-reanimated-table": "^0.0.2",
"react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
"react-native-screen-brightness": "^2.0.0-alpha",
"react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
"react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.3.2",
"react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
"react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
"typed-async-storage": "^3.1.2"
},
"resolutions": {
"@expo/config-plugins": "5.0.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.24.0"
},
"private": true
}

Thanks for the help !

To avoid stability issues, specify exact versions for all dependencies in android/app/build.gradle. Using + in versions can pull in unstable or pre-release versions, causing conflicts.
Before
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
implementation 'com.braze:android-sdk-ui:+'

This setup risks fetching unexpected updates, which might depend on unstable libraries like androidx.core:core:1.15.0-alpha01.
After
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.5.0'
implementation 'com.braze:android-sdk-ui:32.1.0'

Tip: Run ./gradlew app:dependencyInsight --configuration <compileClasspath> --dependency androidx.core:core to identify which dependency relies on androidx.core:core. This helps you pinpoint and downgrade any unstable dependencies. Specifying exact versions ensures stable, predictable builds.

Only changing targetSdk and compileSdk version, solved my issue:
android {
namespace = "com.geekytaurus.taskmanagerstatus"
compileSdk = 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.geekytaurus.taskmanagerstatus"
    minSdk = 26
    targetSdk = 34


In file build.gradle.kts (:app) in folder res change
compileSdk = 35

targetSdk = 34

Remember that the compileSdk you choose must be compatible with the API level of the virtual device

CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+S  gives you popup window where you find under "Modules"->"Properties"->Compile SDK Version -> 35 is the option you are looking for.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I could get it compile with targetSdk = 32 but it has to 33 to get on google play
//noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
targetSdk = 32
