Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-35
For some reasons, I ended up with installing the latest android studio on June/2024 (Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1).
I encountered the incompatibility error for androidx.core:core:1.15.0-alpha01 (REF: 6629458). Following the IDE suggestion to update compileSdk of at least 35, I updated the SDK version to 35:
android {
    namespace = "com.example.myprj"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myprj"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 35

I also set up the Android 15 SDK which I believed corresponding to SDK/API level 35 (REF: Android API Levels). Why the Android Studio Koala IDE kept complaining Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-35?

Please review your first link again. As of 2024-06-15 Android 15 is still in beta so the use of API version numbers in your gradle files won't work.

@StevenLee StevenLee have you checked my answer? Hope it solves your problem. Additionally if you face any other issue you may ask in comment of my answer.

Yes, I checked. Then revert to Android API 34. Thank you for detail answer.


Wait till aug 2024 as android 35 is in beta. Consider using Android API 34 (Upside Down Cake version 14)

Part 1

Currently platform stability is being taken care off by google Developers. Android 15 which is a Developer Preview Version, and is unstable right now So as of now keep using android 34 as shown in below code.
android {
    namespace = "com.example.prjname"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.prjname"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34

Reference links -

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15/migration

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15/reference/compat-framework-changes

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15/behavior-changes-all

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/now-in-android-106-1b72759c5f0c



Report Issue if you face any at
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15/feedback#issue_tracker
And track them at

https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/6678935

https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/6679723


Create New Issue :

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190602&template=1942052


Other bug reporting options :

Report Android Studio bugs here

Report build tools and Gradle bugs here

Report Android Emulator bugs here




Part 2 (use it after getting stable release)
If you are using AGP 7.0.0 or higher, update your app's build.gradle
How to use it in future :
android {
    compileSdkPreview "VanillaIceCream"
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkPreview "VanillaIceCream"
    }
}


https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15/behavior-changes-15


I accepted @Bob Smith's answer because it is detailed. For someone want to switch back to targetSDK of  34, you can check this answer. I changed to targetSDK  < 35, e.g. 34:
android {
    namespace = "com.example.prjname"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.prjname"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34

Also, choose the latest stable libs as pointed in here.

plus one to you

I encountered the same issue, but upgrading to a compatible Gradle plugin resolved it
you check this link Gradle compatible version

To resolve this issue you can do following

1.Download Koala
2.build.gradle `plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.5.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.20' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.5.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.50' apply false
}`

3. gradle-wrapper.properties `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip`

